# Send array and image with HTTP POST in swift

Tags: ios, swift, post, http-post, swift4

I'm trying to upload an image with parameters in Swift. I have a problem with an array in the parameters

post request look like this.

```
 curl --request POST \
  --url http://example.com/api/v2/upload-single-photo-restaurant \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  --form lat=21.584739 \
  --form lng=105.807110 \
  --form device_id=TG23X44C \
  --form name=Kitacy \
  --form 'datetime=2018-05-15 08:54:00' \
  --form 'categories[]=1' \
  --form 'categories[]=2' \
  --form photo=undefined
```

link code: https://ideone.com/mSGWkD

This is my current code

```
func myImageUploadRequest()
    {

        let myUrl = URL(string: "https://example.com/api/v2/upload-single-photo-restaurant");
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:myUrl!);
        request.httpMethod = "POST";
        let device_id = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
        print("lat is:",lat!)
        print("lng is:",lng!)
        var param:[String:Any] = [
                "lat" : lat!,
                "lng" : lng!,
                "device_id" : device_id,
                "name" : photoName.text!,
                "datetime" : Const.getDate()
                ] as [String : Any]


        let boundary = "----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imgView.image!, 1)
        if(imageData==nil)  { return; }
        request.httpBody = createBodyWithParameters(parameters: param as? [String : String], filePathKey: "photo", imageDataKey: imageData! as NSData, boundary: boundary) as Data

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }

            // You can print out response object
            print("******* response = \(String(describing: response))")

            // Print out reponse body
            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            print("****** response data = \(responseString!)")

            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary

                print(json!)

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.imgView.image = UIImage(named: "img")
                    let msg = json?.object(forKey: "message")
                    UIViewController.removeSpinner(spinner: self.sv!)
                    self.stackViewUpload.isHidden=true
                    self.alertWithMsg(msg: msg as! String)
                })
            }catch{
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?, imageDataKey: NSData, boundary: String) -> NSData {
        let body = NSMutableData();

        if parameters != nil {
            for (key, value) in parameters! {
                body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
                body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
                body.appendString(string: "\(value)\r\n")
            }
        }

        let filename = "user-profile.jpg"
        let mimetype = "image/jpg"

        body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
        body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
        body.appendString(string: "Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
        body.append(imageDataKey as Data)
        body.appendString(string: "\r\n")

        body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)--\r\n")

        return body

}
extension NSMutableData {

        func appendString(string: String) {
            let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
            append(data!)
        }
}
```

link code: https://ideone.com/CPj1CO

Now how can I add a category(Integer) array to the 'categories []' key into the parameters ?

Comment: u can use alamofire to upload images in swift

Comment: @DilipTiwari I tried search about alamofire but I still can not do it. can you suggest me links or tutorials ?

Comment: sure i will plz wait

Comment: i have given one answer also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50041287/how-to-upload-multipart-image-to-server-using-alamofire/50042787#50042787   or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26121827/uploading-file-with-parameters-using-alamofire